# To use "emulatePrepare" in Yii or not?

Tags: php, mysql, yii, pdo

I have copied unmodified (I think) code for Yii's database connection from manual / demo app / whatever. And, if I'm not mistaken, it has `'emulatePrepare'=>TRUE` set by default.

Then I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10455228/1469208) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15718418/1469208) answer and many more sources, which all seems to be claiming, that **using emulate prepares is wrong idea**. That it is some kind of relic from an old versions of RDBMS (particularly MySQL in my case) and should not be used on modern versions of MySQL/PHP.

Can someone confirm that? Should we have `'emulatePrepare'=>FALSE` in our Yii apps?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both answers you have linked to are quite pointless and subjective. **They fail to provide a certain reason for avoiding emulation mode**. No wonder though, as there is not a single one.

There are only two real live cases known to me which really affects experience with PDO

- when emulation is turned **on**, then one cannot use passing parameter in `execute()` for the LIMIT statement.
- when emulation is turned **off**, then one cannot use quite handy feature of using more than one named placeholder with same name.

So, the final decision is up yo you, but I wouldn't call any issue too critical.

Comment: Thank you. So, from your answer, it seems, that claims like: "_emulate prepare was good for old versions of RDBMs, but for modern ones it is just slower_" (found at least few of them), we should treat like blah-blah, right?

Comment: This particular one is rather not true. As it (properly) noted in the other answer, it's quite contrary - `"native prepared statements may be a little slower than issuing a plain textual query using emulated prepared statements."`

Comment: Plus: there is [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8776392/1469208): "_`EMULATE_PREPARES=true` seems to be the default setting for the pdp_mysql driver right now. The query cache thing has been fixed/change since then (...)_". Thanks, again!

Comment: This one is rather irrelevant. Query cache issue were applicable only to `emulate=>FALSE` case (making it even slower). But it is fixed nowadays anyway.