# php query doesnt work

Tags: php, sql

Hello I was building my Query class which I saw on YouTube, but I'm stuck. My Query function that allows you to use advanced SQL queries like `SELECT * FROM market LIMIT ? OFFSET ?` It binds values so I can't find any solution. Anybody help? What should I do?

My Query.php class contains

```
public function query($sql, $params = array())
{
    $this->_error = false;

    if ($this->_query = $this->db->prepare($sql))
    {
        $x = 1;

        if (count($params))
        {
            foreach ($params as $param)
            {
                $this->_query->bindValue($x, $param);
                $x++;
            }
        }

        if ($this->_query->execute())
        {
            $this->_results = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount();
        } else {
            $this->_error = true;
        }
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Here I tried to select items from db like it's in my Query bellow

```
$i = 3;
$x = 100;
$sql = Query::getInstance()->query("SELECT * FROM market LIMIT ? OFFSET ?", array($i, $x));

var_dump($sql);
```

I didn't put here full source code, I think there is a problem in query function but I'm not able to find it.

ERROR IMAGE
[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269840/how-to-apply-bindvalue-method-in-limit-clause

Comment: And there are more than 100 entries in the database? It seems the query runs - it seems it returns bool(true), which, if I understand that mess of a var_dump() correctly, that the query runs.

Comment: But there is problem that error = bool(true) it means that something went wrong, it seems like executing the query

Comment: Run `SELECT * FROM market LIMIT 3 OFFSET 100;` directly in your database and tell us what error you are getting.  p.s. `Query` is probably not a good name for your database connection -- not intuitive.

Comment: It actually works, the problem was PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Php Prepared Statements Turn Emulation Off](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15718148/php-prepared-statements-turn-emulation-off)

Comment: There are many SO questions that answer this question, I flagged using just one.  In the future, exhaustively search SO before posting a question, because the chances are: someone has already asked your question and someone else has already answered it.  SO is a wonderful resource, please use it to the fullest.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks nogad,
All i do is set this at the beginning of query function:

```
$this->db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false );
```